# Creating a simple DOJO Line chart from JSON data

Tags: json, dojo

I have tried without success to plot a simple line chart in DOJO using jSON data and would greatly appreciate any help.

I have the following snip of data being returned:

```
[{"id":"24","Entry":"2012-02-10","Symbol":"Various","Type":"Speculativ","Call1":"0","Call2":"0","Put1":"0","Put2":"0","Cost":"0.00","Qty":"0","PnL":"383","R":"0.00","Risk":"6691"},    
{"id":"23","Entry":"2012-02-01","Symbol":"VariousSp","Type":"Vertical","Call1":"0","Call2":"0","Put1":"0","Put2":"0","Cost":"0.00","Qty":"0","PnL":"341","R":"0.00","Risk":"19160"}]
```

I have tried to plot directly from the data store, building an array, all to no avail.  I'm very new to Dojo so I'm fairly sure I am making a simple mistake -

My code (as it currently exists is as follows):

```
var PnLStore;
    var cumPnL = [];

    require([
            "dojox/charting/Chart",
            "dojo/store/JsonRest",
            "dojo/store/Memory",
            "dojo/store/Cache",
            "dojox/charting/StoreSeries",
            "dojox/charting/plot2d/Lines",
            "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
            "dojox/charting/themes/Dollar",
            "dojox/charting/plot2d/Markers",
            "dojo/domReady!"],

            function( Chart, JsonRest, Memory, Cache, StoreSeries, Lines) {

                    PnLStore = Cache(JsonRest({target:"pullTradesClosed.php"}), Memory());

                    var chart = new Chart("chartDiv");

                    chart.addPlot("default", {
                            type: "Lines",
                            markers: true
                    });

                    chart.addAxis("x");
                    chart.addAxis("y", { vertical: true, fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major" });

                    PnLStore.query({id:"id"}).forEach(
                      function(trade) {
                        cumPnL.push (Number(trade.PnL));
                    });

                    chart.addSeries("PnL", cumPnL, {stroke:"green"});
                    chart.render(); 

            });
```

While it may not be obvious, I am trying to plot ID versus PnL.

Comment: Try to check that cumPnL is not empty when you add a series.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind the chart to a datastore, like you are doing, it is best to use the storeseries:

```
chart.addSeries("y", new StoreSeries(store, { query: {} }, "PnL"));
```

see:
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/charting_advanced/

for examples

You may also use dataseries:

addSeries("PnL", new dojox.charting.DataSeries(store, {query:{}}, "PnL")).

See:
[Dojox charting programattically using store series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556595/dojox-charting-programattically-using-store-series)
for a related question